# Can a Meteor web app serve data to an iOS app?

Tags: ios, json, mongodb, meteor

Pretty straight forward question i think. I have created a web app in meteor and its using mongoDB storage. I have UI to update the data in the backend through the web app.

The question then becomes, I have designed an iOS app that i would really love for it to read the data being served to the web app from the mongoDB. As it stands, the app takes a url to a JSON file that i update regularly and serializes it accordingly. I want to pass on the tasks of updating the backend but exposing company employees to the potential mess of JSON backend, where missing/deleting a bracket / brace causes the app to break is out of the question.

My question is, since the meteor web app stores data as JSON documents, is there a way i can access the same JSON from the iOS app? It would really help because then, the person updating the backend only deals with UI, not code. I know this is a pretty broad question, but any pointers would be fantastic. Links, tutorials, frameworks to learn... anything. I've been googling around but can't seem to find anything solid.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into using one of the many iOS based DDP clients, like [this one](https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios). With these libraries you can connect native iOS apps to the backend of any deployed Meteor app.

Comment: thanks a lot for this. exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are looking for a way to get/update the data of your meteor server from the IOS app.

To do that, you can expose an API, like a REST one. Basically, your IOS app will call your Meteor server via HTTP and send/receive JSON data. Like that, you can get your collections, update, add, delete their items as well. There is a lot of literature around [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

I used a very old one that I do not recommend because it is not maintained anymore, I will put the link anyway [Old Rest API](https://github.com/crazytoad/meteor-collectionapi).

I invite you to have a look at atmosphere, the meteor package library: [Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com). I did a quick search on it and I found this package that looks promising: [Simple Rest](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/rest).

Have a look at the packages on Atmosphere, you can use 'rest' as keyword and pick the one that fits your needs. I am especially thinking of security ;).